# Can't get Epson Perfection V500 drivers to work

Tags: drivers, scanner

I'm an absolute beginner to Ubuntu (having at last broken the chains of XP!!) but I'm struggling with a lot of things as I lack the basic 'language' skills you all seem to use; but here goes:

I dutifully followed the instructions given on Nov 15 '12 by "user 76204" in an effort to get my scanner going.

The instructions are clear and simple [I updated to allow for 14.04 / 32 bit] and installed the following packages all in the right order [several times]:

`iscan-data_1.29.02_all.deb`

`iscan2.29.3-1~usbo.1.ltdl7_i386.deb`

`iscan-plugin` etc

Rebooted system ....... nothing happens ..... no scanner/no nothing.

Any help will inspire incredible gratitude as I'm beginning to think I may have made a big mistake and that Linux is for you pro's and not the likes of me ..... but I 'endeavour to persevere'

Thanx in advance

Baz.

Answer (score 0):

Install the common scanner drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install sane xsane xsane-common sane-utils libsane libsane-common libsane-dbg libsane-dev libsane-extras libsane-extras-common libsane-extras-dbg libsane-extras-dev
```

Then use the scanner with the application `simple-scan`

Comment: Thanx for advice. Installed scanner drivers as advised but still nothing. When rebooting or switching on the scanner nothing seems to happen, the scanner just is not being 'seen' by the laptop and the software is not launching at all. Any other thoughts would be appreciated. Regards Baz